# Ajax 'POST' again after the data received is modified

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object

I get the data from backend after Ajax post is being made, that data will have list of values. as user chooses a value from the list I want it to update to my object and post the ajax call again.

The problem I am facing here is I am not able to post again with chooses values, I need only one ajax call to do this. the nested ajax calls would not suffice

```
var searchObject = {
  "research": "test"
}
$.ajax({
  method: method,
  data: JSON.stringify(searchObject), // while making next call the searchObject should have. "list":value of x in success
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: requestUrl
})
 .success(function(data) {
  var x = data.list2


}).error(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that u can use syn ajax request rather than asyn request.You can see it from the jquery api [Jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

And and you can try code like this:

```js
var searchObject = {
  "research": "test"
}
let x = undefined;
$.ajax({
  async:false,
  method: method,
  data: JSON.stringify(searchObject), // while making next call the searchObject should have. "list":value of x in success
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: requestUrl
})
 .success(function(data) {
   x = data.list2


}).error(function() {

});

//Another syn ajax post 
$.ajax({
  async:false,
  method: method,
  data: JSON.stringify(x), // while making next call the searchObject should have. "list":value of x in success
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: requestUrl
})
 .success(function(data) {
   console.log(data)

}).error(function() {

});
```

Comment: I tried this approach but as said, I don't want two ajax calls

Answer (score 0):

If you're using POST with Ajax, this should do it for you. Just create a file and called it testing.php and enter a value in the input field and you'll see that ajax sends data to backEnd successfully. Hope it helps!

```
<?php

 $data = array();
  if(isset($_POST['research'])){
  $data = $_POST['research'];       
  echo json_encode($data);  
 die();      
 }
 ?>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>

  <form>
    Enter value: <input type="text" id="someID"><br>
<input value="submit" type="submit">
 </form>
   <p id="msg"><p/>

<script type = "text/javascript">

$("form").on("submit", function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var emailfield = $("#someID").val();
    var myText ='You entered: ' + emailfield;

    $.ajax({
        url: "testing.php",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {research: myText},
        success: function (result) {
            alert("result: " + result);
            $("#msg").html(result);
        },
        error: function (params) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
    });

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot for looking into it. my criteria is different. I get data for POST, store that value, may be in a variable and add it to object and post again

Comment: @john to post it again you can simply update the value of mytext variable and it should POST the data for you.

Comment: actually that doesn't work since the ajax call being made on page load and on choosing each filter the page refreshes. pls advise